# Table with even numbers?

Tags: c#, random

I have code like this to display a table 10 by 10.

I want it to display even numbers between 2 and 10 but I can't make it work.

This table show numbers from 2 to 11 with even and odd numbers. How can I make it to show even only?

This is what I have now:

```
int[,] table = new int[10, 10];
Random r1 = new Random();
int num8 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        tabela[i, j] = r1.Next(2,11);
        if (table[i, j] ==8)
            num8 = num8 + 1;
      }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)

        Console.Write(table[i, j] + " ");
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("In the table we can find: " + num8 + ", number 8.");
```

Comment: make i and j go up to 5 and while accessing multiply by 2?

Comment: Look at the % operator. It will give you the remainder of a division

Comment: does this code even compile/work? you assign to `tabela` but then check the `table` cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Random.Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method takes an exclusive upper bound. Since you want only even numbers, you can use:

```
r1.Next(1, 6) * 2
```

for generating the numbers. `r1.Next(1, 6)` will give you numbers from the set: 1,2,3,4,5. Doubling the results gives you the following possibilities: 2,4,6,8,10.

Comment: Do you know maybe for odd number too? Let's say from 1, 9. (1, 3, 5, 7, 9). Is it simliar as for even or is it completely different?

Comment: @MihaM It's similar and really easy - just take a pencil, a piece of paper and give yourself some time to figure it out. Write down what you have (2,4,6,8,10) and what you want (1,3,5,7,9) - and try simplest mathematical operations to find the one that gives you what you need. First find the idea, don't think about the code. I will help if you won't manage to find it yourself, but please do try first - it will give you more satisfaction and will make you learn faster.

Comment: Thanks, got it. :) Just needed to add -1 after *2.

Comment: @MihaM Great! Cheers! :)